# PostgreSQL Backup: how to activate backup mode non-interactively

Tags: backup, postgresql, snapshot

Hello PostgreSQL experts!

I'm running a postgresql 15 server with multiple database instances ("clusters"), which uses Netapp NFS as storage for the data and WAL directories. I'm trying to achieve a storage snapshot-level backup where I activate backup mode with e.g.:

```
psql -e "SELECT pg_backup_start('backup-1', fast => true);"
```

on all instances, then issue a snapshot command to the storage for the data and WAL volumes, and afterwards disable backup mode on all databases again.

However, it seems that the `pg_backup_start()` function must be triggered interactively, and the moment the psql shell closes, the backup mode is canceled again. This of course invalidates the idea of this backup method, as the snapshot would contain inconsistent data.

Question: how do I non-interactively activate "backup mode" on a postgresql 15 database, or from a shell script in a way so that I can perform other actions in the script, without the database dropping out of backup mode in between?

Details:

- postgresql-15 (15.5-1.pgdg120+1)
- Debian 12 x86_64
- packages from official DEB repo from Postgres (http://apt.postgresql.org)
- NFS / Netapp Ontap 9.x

Thanks in advance for your input and help!

Answer (score 0):

b2c, I would try to use pg_ctl commands instead of psql:

```
pg_ctl -D $PGDATA start fast
```

`# snapshot commands here`

```
pg_ctl -D $PGDATA stop
```